# How do I open multiple terminals, so I can have multiple shells open?

Tags: linux, fedora, terminal

I have been slowly learning Gnu/Linux commands, and I'm using it to get more serious about my python programming. While reading about python on Gnu/Linux its uses and integrated shell, plus using the terminal. I'm curious how to have multiple terminals open, as when I try to open a new shell, it just brings my current terminal to the front. I'm using Fedora on a laptop.

Comment: What desktop are you using? This will be the deciding factor. (Try right clicking on the icon.)

Comment: And if all else fails, you can start a new terminal emulator window from your existing shell, e.g. `xterm &` if you are using `xterm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open multiple terminals in Fedora, Open the terminal, go to the menu bar, and click File > New Window or File > New Tab. Personally, I prefer the latter as you can just switch between tabs and then bring the whole window up and have all of them available. Each tab is a different shell session just as each window is.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want more terminals open and to view all of them in the same time. If you are using GUI you can grab your tab and move them around, resize them, and stick it anywhere on the screen,like you move any other app. If you are using CLI you can use `tmux` program.